# How to config routerLink from component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Below routing working perfectly, but I wanted to handle the same functionality from component instead of HTML.

How do I do ?

**HTML**

```
<a [routerLink]="[ '..', card.item ]">VIEW MORE</a>
```

Comment: can you elaborate ?

Comment: I wanted to control the routerLink from component level and not in html, is any way to do it ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this for relative navigation:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

moveTo() {
  this.router.navigate(['..', card.item], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

and add your click method in html

```
<a (click)="moveTo()">VIEW MORE</a>
```

Comment: Do i need to do anything in HTML ?

Comment: i've updated the answer, you need to add click event in your html

Comment: This solution does not work for accessibility. Anchor tags require an href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> You can use `Router`

```
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    constructor(
        private router: Router,
    ) {}

   navigateTo(card){
       this.router.navigate([ '..', card.item ]);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create shared service for navigation:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class NavigationService {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
  }

  public goToProduct(productId: number): void {
    this.router.navigate(['..', productId]);
  }
}
```